# Ggplot2: manually assign the different sizes of the text and thickness of the line simultaneously?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need chart lines to be with predefined thickness and the label sizes with a predefined size. The labels of the thicker line should be bigger.

Input data:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(1:10, 1:10),
                B = runif(20),
                C = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)))
```

I can easily assign necessary thickness of the line depending on the variable:

```
lines.size = c(2, 0.7)
names(lines.size) = c("A", "B")

ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B, group = C, color = C)) +
  geom_line(aes(size = C)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = B + 0.1, label = round(B, 1))) +
  scale_size_manual(values = lines.size)
```

Same way I can assign the size of the labels:

```
label.size = c(5, 2)
names(label.size) = c("A", "B")
    
ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B, group = C, color = C)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(y = B + 0.1, label = round(B, 1), size = C)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = label.size)
```

ggplot2 allows only one scale_size_manual. Is there any way to control both label size and thickness of the line?

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this using `ggnewscale` package and the function `new_scale()` where you define the geom you want to add, in this case `size`:

```
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)
#Inputs
lines.size = c(2, 0.7)
names(lines.size) = c("A", "B")
label.size = c(5, 2)
names(label.size) = c("A", "B")
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B, group = C, color = C)) +
  geom_line(aes(size = C)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = lines.size)+
  new_scale("size")+
  geom_text(aes(y = B + 0.1, label = round(B, 1), size = C)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = label.size)
```

Output:

[image]